# Should my Flutter App instantiate a new object if I'm using Firestore as a backend?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

for the technically-savy people out there. I'm building a flutter app with a firestore backend and I've been doing some research as to the best way to structure my models. Tutorials online show different methods and I can't figure out what's the best one as I want my app to be light but also use Firestore efficiently so it doesn't cost too much.

Those are the ways I've encountered so far:

1. Have model for the flutter object and another one for the firestore object. Everytime I get the data from firestore I instanciate a firestore object and map it into a flutter object or create a new flutter object and then have a listener there to update my whole app.
2. Have one model for the flutter/firestore object. Everytime I get data from firestore I need to instantiate it once. No mapping. I have a listener there.
3. Get the data directly from firestore without needing to instantiate an object and print the documents there, and have a streamprovider to get the data.

I'd really appreciate your help in structuring my app/project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider all your requirements, technical and business. The definition of your architecture should entails this needs. If you rush to choose an architecture that in the future would be needed to be re-defined, then it could be more expensive.

Once you have considered this, then you should think in your architecture. Try to share your general workflow.

> I want my app to be light but also use Firestore efficiently so it doesn't cost too much.

All the three options you have shared fit to your needs? Is there a step in your solution in which the steps of your three options would fail?

I think you should base the architecture more on your needs than in which is least cost.